# R dplyr/array demean adding a column with the rowmeans

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have a dataframe which I want to demean all rows and add a last column which has the mean.  I don't want to hardcode the column names, and I'm fine with use arrays/matrices (though I'd be interested in learning it functionally in dplyr also).  Suppose I start with

```
 tibble(x=seq(1.0,4.0),y=seq(5.,8))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     5
2     2     6
3     3     7
4     4     8
```

I want to end up with

```
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    -2     2     3
2    -2     2     4
3    -2     2     5
4    -2     2     6
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rowwise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html)

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x = seq(1.0, 4.0),y = seq(5., 8))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(c_across(x:y))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x:y), ~ .x - avg))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       x     y   avg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    -2     2     3
#> 2    -2     2     4
#> 3    -2     2     5
#> 4    -2     2     6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R approach with `sweep` -

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1.0,4.0),y=seq(5.,8))
rm <- rowMeans(df)
df <- sweep(df, 1, rm)
df$z <- rm
df

#   x y z
#1 -2 2 3
#2 -2 2 4
#3 -2 2 5
#4 -2 2 6
```